# Strange HTML as result of NSURLConnection request

Tags: html, objective-c, caching, nsurlconnection, meta-tags

I have a strange problem...

I need to send a GET HTTP Request to web site by NSURLConnection (`[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest`...).

All works very well but sometimes I see a strange html result different from what I expect. 
This garbage html is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> -->
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0.1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<TITLE></TITLE></HEAD><BODY><P></BODY>
</HTML>
```

(Lines split for clarity)

What does that mean?

The web site to which I refer is not mine so I can not work on the server side to solve the issue.

Can I do anything to prevent this?

Comment: What does your request look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the server (or an intermediary, like a load balancer) is asking you to make the request again in .1 seconds.

If you viewed this page with a web browser, it would wait .1 seconds, and then refresh the page (the purpose of the `Refresh` meta tag).

You will probably need to check explicitly for this, and retry your request (after waiting .1 seconds to be polite) when it happens.